# UIView addSubview and the subview isn't displayed

Tags: ios, uiview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    HeadViewController *headViewController = [[HeadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HeadViewController" bundle:nil];    
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120)];
    [view addSubview:headViewController.vew];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

HeadViewController.h:

```
@interface HeadViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *view;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIView *view;
@end
```

and I connect the view to the file's owner.

And I can't see the `headViewController.view`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to define the `view` outlet in the `HeadViewController` class. It is automatically inherited from the `UIViewController` super class.

Then, I suggest you to add directly the view of `HeadViewController` to your current view. Eg.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     HeadViewController *headViewController = [[HeadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HeadViewController" bundle:nil];    
     headViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120);
     [self.view addSubview:headViewController.view];
}
```

But, if you are using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), the `headViewController` instance will probably be deallocated after the end of the `viewDidLoad` method. It is convenient (and I'd say it is compulsory) to assign that instance to a local variable in the controller you are currently displaying. This way you will be able to handle its view's components later if needed, the instance will be retained, and everything else will work perfectly. You should have something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     self.headViewController = [[HeadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HeadViewController" bundle:nil];    
     headViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120);
     [self.view addSubview:headViewController.view];
}
```

and

```
@interface MyController ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) HeadViewController *headViewController;
@end
```

in the hidden interface definition at the beginning of the `.m` class implementation file.

Comment: I correct you: headViewController.view is nil, if it not added as subview. need to swap addsubview and set the frame

Comment: Check my update about ARC. If `headViewController.view` is `nil`, double check the connection of the view with the controller in the nib file. Is it `nil` just inside this method (outlet issue) or after it has finished (ARC issue)?

Comment: I changed the code,just like you told me,and I define a view because I delete the default one. And there is still no headViewController.view...i am confused.

Comment: Is the File's owner object in the NIB file defined as a `HeadViewController` object? And did you check the outlet connection? If everything is properly configured it has to work. Otherwise I don't know how to help you, sorry. Is the `headViewController` value a non-nil value?

Comment: Probably an issue with the NIB name you are using?

Comment: I have tried ever method you just told me , and it does not work out. And I create another ViewController, it's OK now...I just want to know why? Thanks.Have a good day!

Comment: I just had this, forgot to use loadNibNamed instead of alloc/init, but that's for the a UIView, not controller class with nib

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a typo - forgot the i in .view

[view addSubview:headViewController.vew];

Comment: That might be correct, but it looks like the op already solved this issue a long time ago...

Answer (score 0):

i is missing in the syntax

[view addSubview:headViewController.view];

Comment: The answer was provided 2 years back. What is purpose now?